# A 2-sphere bounding a 3-ball?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm reading Hatcher's "Notes on Basic $3$-Manifold Topology" and he quickly refers to the notion of a $2$-sphere embedded in a $3$-manifold, which bounds or not an embedded $3$-ball, but without previous explanation. This is confusing.

A $2$-sphere, topologically speaking, is a space homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2$, and a $3$-ball is a space homeomorphic to $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ with $||x||< 1$, or just $\mathbb{R}^3$.

So, rigorously speaking, what's this notion?

Comment: It's most likely exactly what it says. When you have an embedding of a $3$-ball (in the three-dimensional Euclidean space, I assume), you can look at its boundary, which can either be (homeomorphic to) a $2$-sphere or not (it could be empty, or it could be the horned sphere, for instance).

Comment: Well, we need not be in $\mathbb{R}^3$, but that's not a problem. Think that we just have an embedding of $\mathbb{S}^2$ into the manifold, and the image will bound some region. So it's more of the converse of what you are saying.

Comment: Well, if you embed $S^2$ *anywhere*, I see no reason for it to bound any region in any reasonable sense.

Comment: If you embedd a 3-ball in the manifold the interior of its image will be the image of the usual 3-ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$, using a topological invariance of domain argument, so it will be homeomorphic to the usual 3-ball. So, this is trivial.
What do you mean by a region in a reasonable sense?

Comment: @tomasz The Alexander horned sphere is a pathological imbedding of a 2-sphere, but it's still homeomorphic to a 2-sphere.

Comment: In my last comment I was referring to the closure of the 3-ball. If you embedd the (open) 3-ball, you may get the entire manifold, so there's no boundary to speak about.

Comment: Nobody will answer this correctly?

Comment: We say a 2-sphere embedded into a 3-manifold bounds a ball if the chosen embedding extends to an embedding of the ball into the 3-manifold.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeMiller, that definition seems reasonable. Now, could you cite some book or paper where I could read a little more of this? Where did you see it?

Comment: Nope, and I don't know. I'm not sure how much there is to read about the definition itself. I can clarify further if you have more questions.

Comment: Of course there's not much to read about any definition, just assume it, but that's when you read it in some book. Now, what I want to know (and I'll be even more precise this time) is: where did you read it? Somedy posted the definition on his (her) Facebook page and all the mathematical comunity accepted it so? Or there's some math book which mencion it?
You don't have to believe me, search on google, there's no mencion of the definition, just uses of the notion.

Comment: Compare a 1-sphere (circle) in an ordinary torus. If the circle lies completely within a small simply connected coordinate patch and does not self-intersect, it will bound a disc. If it goes around the donut hole, it bounds nothing

Comment: Correct. Now, how is this helpful?

Comment: A good book to look at for this sort of stuff is John Hempel's 3-Manifolds.

Comment: Thanks @Charlie, excellent reference

Answer (score 2):

When someone in geometric topology says the $n$-ball, they almost always mean the space $B^n=\{x\in \Bbb R^n : ||x||_2 \leq 1\} $ where $||\_||_2$ is the usual Euclidean 2-norm. $S^{n-1}=\{x\in \Bbb R^n : ||x||_2 = 1\}$ is a subspace of this space in the obvious way. If one has an embedding $i:S^{n-1} \to M$ one can ask if there exists an embedding $\tilde i: B^n \to M$ with $\tilde i=i$ when we restrict to $S^{n-1}$. If such an embedding exists we say the embedded $n-1$-sphere (corresponding to the image of $i$) bounds an embedded $n$-ball.